# Android app problem reading phone number of a contact

Tags: android, sqlite, contacts

Im trying to read the phone number of a contact but I cant get it to work...

My code is exactly the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341463/how-to-read-contact-number-using-android)

---

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);

    if (cur.getCount() > 0) 
    {
        contacts = new String[cur.getCount()];
        numbers = new String[cur.getCount()];
        int index = 0;
        while (cur.moveToNext()) 
        {
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            contacts[index] = name;             
            MyListAdapter listAdapt = new MyListAdapter(MeetUp.this, R.layout.row, contacts);
            MeetUp.this.setListAdapter(listAdapt);


            if ( Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) 
            {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                while(pCur.moveToNext());
                {
                    numbers[index] = pCur.getString( pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));               
                }
            }
            index++;
        }
    }
```

My logcat output:

```
03-25 16:55:08.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5383): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{michaels.meeting/michaels.meeting.MeetUp}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1
03-25 16:55:08.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5383):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787)
03-25 16:55:08.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5383):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
03-25 16:55:08.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5383):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-25 16:55:08.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5383):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2136)
03-25 16:55:08.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5383):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 16:55:08.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5383):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
03-25 16:55:08.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5383):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
03-25 16:55:08.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5383):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 16:55:08.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5383):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-25 16:55:08.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5383):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-25 16:55:08.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5383):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-25 16:55:08.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5383):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 16:55:08.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5383): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1
03-25 16:55:08.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5383):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
03-25 16:55:08.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5383):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
03-25 16:55:08.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5383):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
03-25 16:55:08.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5383):     at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:140)
03-25 16:55:08.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5383):     at michaels.meeting.MeetUp.onCreate(MeetUp.java:47)
03-25 16:55:08.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5383):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
03-25 16:55:08.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5383):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
03-25 16:55:08.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5383):     ... 11 more
```

The contact that it fails definitely has a number but after debugging I think that pCur doesnt have a column for numbers..Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks in advance -- mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what the problem was! The while loop and specifically the moveToNext() call was making it crash..works fine if you get rid of the loop!

```
pCur.moveToFirst();
numbers[index] = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need a `cursor.moveToFirst()` call before you start enumerating.

Comment: Which line in your code is causing the exception to be thrown?

Comment: K This one: numbers[index] = pCur.getString( pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to Retrieve Contacts :

```
        ContentResolver cr1 = getContentResolver();
    String[] projection = new String[] {People._ID,People.NAME,People.NUMBER};
    Uri contacts =  People.CONTENT_URI;
    // Make the query. 
    Cursor managedCursor = cr1.query(contacts, projection, null, null, People.NAME + " ASC");
        if (managedCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            String contactname; 
            String cphoneNumber; 
            int nameColumn = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(People.NAME); 
            int phoneColumn = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(People.NUMBER);
            do {
                // Get the field values
                contactname = managedCursor.getString(nameColumn);
                cphoneNumber = managedCursor.getString(phoneColumn);
                if((cphoneNumber!= "" && cphoneNumber!=null)|| (contactname!="" && contactname!=null)){
                    c_Name.add(contactname);
                    c_Number.add(cphoneNumber);
                }
            } while (managedCursor.moveToNext());
        }
```

This will retreive the Name and Number ...

Comment: Yeah I came across a similar tutorial myself but this is using deprecated APIs and I'm trying to avoid that! Any other solution?